# access struts employee object in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have list of employees on JSP page coming from struts action class. I want to access this list in my javascript code.  I tried following

In my JSP I have

```
 <s:hidden value = "%{employeeList}"  id = "employeeListId" />
```

In my JS file I have

```
  var employeeList=  $("#employeeListId").val();
    alert(employeeList);
```

But I get something like following.

[com.lifetech.magellan.bean.empListColumns@6d234585, com.lifetech.magellan.bean.empListColumns@10c119d6, com.lifetech.magellan.bean.empListColumns@5eed22c0]

I need to read each attribute of each employee such as 
employeeName, empNumber etc.

How to do that?

Comment: what is your question?

Comment: An HTML element attribute can only contain text, not an arbitrary Java object. You'll have to convert it to some text format in the JSP, and then parse that back into an object in JS. JSON is probably the easiest.

Answer (score 0):

create array by jstl

```
var employeeList= {
<c:forEach items="${employeeList}" var="employee">
"${employee.id}": {
 name:"${employee.employeeName}",
 job:"${employee.employeeJob}",
    },
</c:forEach>
}
```